# AutoIT script is unable to handle "+" sign

Tags: java, windows, autoit

I have a variable(`fileSource`) in `Java`, which contains `+` sign. I try to paste it into a file chooser dialog window with following code.

```
String autoITExecutable = "C:\\_privat\\filechooser.exe \"" + fileSource + "\"";
```

AutoIT script, `filechooser.exe`:

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
Send($CmdLine[1])
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Value of variable is pasted without `+` signs to dialog window.
Example value of `fileSource`: `C:\_private\input\Files\my_upload1+1+2(original).pdf`
AutoIT use it like: `C:\_private\input\Files\my_upload112(original).pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WinWaitActive("Open")
Send($CmdLine[1], 1)
Send("{ENTER}")
```

[`Send`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm) will interpret `+` as <kbd>shift</kbd> key. Use 2nd parameter of `Send` flag 1 to send raw text.

Comment: Docs from [send-function](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm)

Answer (score 1):

From [autoit Send Function](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm):

> '+' This tells AutoIt to send a SHIFT keystroke; therefore,
>   Send("Hell+o") would send the text "HellO". Send("!+a") would send
>   "ALT+SHIFT+a".

To overcome this, you need

> flag  [optional] Changes how "keys" is processed:
>
> $SEND_DEFAULT (0) = Text contains special characters like + and ! to indicate SHIFT and ALT key-presses (default).
>
> $SEND_RAW (1) = keys are sent raw.

Resulting in :

```
$var = "..... + .... +" // string containing special characters - "+"
Send($var, 1)         // do not interpret, use raw
```